# Trying to publish npx command but getting error

Tags: npm

I also logged in myself and confirm email as well but still getting error.
here is the error:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ahsan-cal - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'ahsan-cal@latest' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-20T14_53_33_993Z-debug-0.log
```

Don't know what's the reason

Comment: I looked on https://www.npmjs.com/ and couldn't see your package. Have you published it?

Comment: @Andy I run ``` npm publish ahsan-cal ``` after login. is there any other way to publish it?